# C++ Using cin.fail(), cin.clear() --- I have an infinite loop and don't know why

Tags: c++

Can you not use cin and then cin.fail() in the same line like this? Is there a cleaner or more standard way to do this type of error checking upon input?--perhaps not using a do-while.

```
do {
     cin.clear();
     cout << "\nPlease enter the size of the array (1-10): ";
} while (cin >> array_size && array_size <= 1 || array_size >= 10 || cin.fail());
```

This one works:

```
do {
    cout << "Please input #: ";
    if (cin.fail()){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    }
    cin >> kids_total;
} while (cin.fail() || kids_total <= 0);
```

Comment: move cin inside the loop

Comment: @ta.speot.is: This doesn't have much to do with operator precedence.

Comment: @TonyD, LightnessRacesinOrbit I was not as careful as I should have been when reading the code. You are both correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cin >> array_size && array_size <= 1 || array_size >= 10 || cin.fail()
```

Say you've got a letter next in `cin`, `cin >> array_size` evaluates `false` so the `&&` short-circuit evalusation skips over `array_size <= 1` to test:

- `array_size >= 10`: might be uninitialised memory read ==> undefined behaviour, otherwise presumably `false`
- `cin.fail()` - definitely `true`

...unless there's undefined behaviour - and maybe even then - the loop will continue *without* having removed the letter from `cin`, only to fail again immediately.

Check `cin.ignore` for a way to remove input that's failed parsing, or use `std::getline(std::cin, my_string)`, `std::istringstream iss(my_string); if (iss >> array_size` etc. for a way to guarantee the entire line's thrown away on bad input....

---

For comparison, this is pretty robust and IMHO intuitive if verbose.  If doing it more than once, just create a function....

```
while (true)
{
    std::cout << "Please input #: ";
    if (std::cin >> kids_total)
    {
        if (kids_total > 0)
            break;
        std::cout << "Value must be > 0, please try again.\n";
    }
    else if (std::cin.eof())
    {
        // rare for keyboard input - e.g. ^D on UNIX/Linux, ^Z Windows
        // can happen with pipes/redirects - e.g. echo 10 20 | ./my_app
        std::cerr << "expected value for kids_total but encountered end of input\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out the following code works perfectly. But for some reason in the if statement, if I put the cin.ignore before the cin.clear, an infinite loop will occur. Why do you think that is? Also, if I don't use the if statement and put the cin.ignore before the cout statement, it won't print and there are about 6 or 7 cin's that take place before the loop quits. Code wasn't formatting so I put it in my first post.

Comment: "an infinite loop will occur. Why do you think that is?" - because when the stream is left in the error state - i.e. not cleared - further operations including `ignore` are just skipped over.  I'll add how I'd implement the loop to my answer so you can compare to what you ended up with....

Comment: One small thing... If the user types "-3-3", cin.ignore will not ignore the second "-3". I thought it will ignore until a new line is found, not a unary operator.

Comment: @LordWalden: in that -3-3 scenario, after a `cin >> kids_total`, `ignore` will indeed remove the second `-3` ***if*** you actually call it, but because the input to `kids_total` worked the `fail` flag will not be set and neither your code nor mine will call `ignore`.  If you think it should, 'best change it.  Cheers.